# Стиль верстки сайта.

Tags: html, css

Всем здравствуйте!

Немного расскажу про то, как я верстаю. Обычно когда мне поступает заказ на верстку после получения макета я его нарезаю и приступаю к верстке. И сначала делаю всю html верстку и когда она вся готова я приступаю к написанию CSS стилей. И вот я задумался как верстают другие разработчики сначала html потом CSS или постепенно например написали кусок html и сразу под него CSS или как я сначала весь html потом CSS? Поделитесь, пожалуйста своими поедпочтениями, коллеги.

Comment: Верстаю блоками по бему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно же, сильно зависит от задачи, от сроков, от настроения даже. Будем исходить из того, что нужно сделать макет, скажем, домашней странцы: времени хоть отбавляй, ограничений - никаких, вдохновения море...

Сперва пишу HTML-ный каркас. Я исхожу из того, что дизайн должен быть отдельно от разметки.  Стараюсь не применять экзотических тегов: div-ы, заголовки и параграфы - моё всё. Делать стараюсь так, чтобы страница смотрелась вменяемо и вообще без вёрстки. Основные меню идут первыми, потом - контент, потом - всяческие сайдбары и пагинация. Не использовать лишних элементов, разного рода фиксов и прочего. А ещё - не дублировать без нужды информацию.

Потом, когда каркас написан - стараюсь писать css так, чтобы без нужды не вмешиваться в разметку, чего бы мне это ни стоило (исправление косяков не в счет).

Результат: к этому каркасу в любой момент можно написать другую таблицу стилей. Так как каркас обычно - результат работы скрипта, вся задача по редизайну будет сводиться к изменению таблицы стилей.

Comment: Экзотические теги — это какие?

Comment: Это header, section, article, nav, footer и т.д.

Comment: @Bars Это новые теги типа article и старые типа addr :D
Я считаю, что в макете им не место. В особенности учитывая популярность IE8.

Span-ам всяким там тоже не место: они должны быть частью контента, который впихивают в этот макет. А для контента - отдельная таблица стилей.

Answer (score 0):

Сверстал основу (неизменяемую): положил `header`, `article`, `footer`; написал для них стили. Сразу же написал стили для основных элементов вроде `p`, `li`, `a` и подобного. Поставил рыбу, проверил[, исправил]. Когда доходит до отдельных элементов, стилизация которых не ограничивается простыми настройкой шрифта, высотой строки (например, стилизация навороченного меню) — тогда занимаюсь отдельно этим стилем. Нередко случается так, что приходится сначала составлять CSS, а уже потом — писать разметку.

Можно и сначала все продумать, представить разметку, что как и куда ставить, но это отнимает лишнее время. Как по мне, верстка — не та задача, к которой нужно подходить сзади. А если такая нужда есть, я считаю, что этот дизайн говенный. Поэтому я и внешний вид (дизайн?!) никогда не представляю в виде изображения, а всегда верстаю.

Это было размышление. Ответ, стало быть: поэтапно.

Comment: > но это отнимает лишнее время

во первых не всегда, во вторых резульатат намного качественее

> я считаю, что этот дизайн говенный

а я считаю что вы считаете его таким потому, что он сложен для вас :)

> верстка — не та задача, к которой нужно подходить сзади

ну да, для любой задачи существует единый, абсолютно универсальный инструмент и верстка здесь не исключение

Comment: Ясно, что нужно сразу понимать, как это должно быть сверстано. Но если в процессе верстки оказывается, что, для того чтобы отобразить пункт меню правильно, придется вложить каждый пункт меню во `.wrapper-outer` и `.wrapper-inner`, под двум концам которых будут `li` и `a` соответственно, то этот макет — говно. Это я к примеру. Конкретно такого случая не было, просто тяжело сейчас привести реальный пример.

Я считаю, что верстка должна быть такой, чтобы, отключив абсолютно все доп. стили (применив нативное отображение элементов), можно было увидеть все на своих местах, без лишних элементов.

Comment: ну все на своих местах вы не увидите, но да вы правы. Без стилей все должно быть понятно

Answer (score 0):

Я использую bootstrap для верстки. Он сам подразумевает определенный стиль html каркаса. Некоторые классы сразу прописываю в html, так как они уже готовые идут из bootstrap CDN. Как только адаптивность блоков и общий стиль настроен, добавляю кастомный stylesheet - создаю и добавляю его классы в html.

```css
bootstrap css CDN
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```